# Probability Question 2 real numbers are chosen at random in the unit interval find the probabilities

Tags: probability

Two real numbers are chosen at random in the unit interval.

Find the probability that their sum exceeds 1
= 1/2

Find the probability that one is more than twice the other.
= 1/4

Find the probability that their sum exceeds one and one is more than twice the other.
= 1/8

Find the probability that their sum exceeds one or one is more than twice the other.
= 1/32

Are these the right answers?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Add this to your question to avoid downvotes and to increase the chance that someone will help you in the sense that your insight in probability will indeed increase. We are not here to do your homework.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include my answers. The post is edited.

Comment: What is your working for the third and fourth answers? The first and second events are not independent, so their probabilities cannot be multiplied to get the third probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes the two real numbers are independently chosen at random from a uniform distribution.

Call the two random numbers $x$ and $y$. Based on the initial assumption, the joint probability density is equal at all points in the unit square, so all probabilities can be interpreted as the total area enclosed by various regions divided by the area of the unit square ($=1$).

The diagram below represents the various conditions (total greater than one, one number more than twice another, etc.) and the regions induced by them. The shaded area represents the third probability.

[image]

### Part A

Your answer is correct. It's the area of $\triangle AGD$.

### Part B

If one number is twice another, then the point $(x,y)$ lies either on the line $y=2x$ or on the line $x=2y$. Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{Pr}[\text{one number} \ge \text{twice other}] &= Area(\triangle OED)+Area(\triangle OBA) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

### Part C

The two numbers must satisfy both conditions, so the total area is that of the shaded regions in the diagram. Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{Pr}[\text{one number} \ge \text{twice other} \text{ AND }x+y\ge1] &= Area(\triangle FED)+Area(\triangle CBA) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}
\end{align}$$

#### Part D

Now the two numbers only satisfy one or more of the conditions in A and B (in part C they needed to satisfy both). So, you should expect a probability that is greater than the one for part C.

You should be able to work out which region the point $(x,y)$ **cannot** be in (a triangle none of whose sides are parallel to the axes), and subtract its area from $1$ to get the required probability.